# I cannot understand the subject exacly of this phrase (DL used in romanization)

Tags: romanization

Wo shi 2002 nian nian de

(this above, I understand, is a date of birth)

Yinwei wo bu tai dong yingwen

Baoqian wo zhi kan de dong DL San ju

(A person showed for me with "DL" and never see this example into a romanization)

Wojia you yang gou

Comment: `Di`???????????

Comment: The first sentence doesn't really make sense, since I wouldn't expect two instances of 年. Also, it's rather time-consuming at times to guess the original characters (which matter) from the pinyin -- would you happen to have them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

我是2002年生的 or 我是2002年来的

因为我不太懂英文

抱歉我只看得懂第三句

我家有养狗

Your second "nian" in the first sentence may be sheng (生，meaning born) or lai (来，meaning came)

I agree with songyuanyao that "DL" may very well be "di". "Di San ju" is "第三句" which means "the third sentence"